# Unexpected result printed after appended to a list

Tags: python, list, append

This is my code:

```
temps = (345, 9876, 23, 100, 567)

new_temps = (temps / 10 for temp in temps)
print(new_temps)
```

The result is an error...

```
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fc8101f76d0>
```

Comment: You aren't appending to a list anywhere. Indeed, there is no list anywhere, only a tuple, `temps`. You say you are new to python, so what exactly did you expect `(temps / 10 for temp in temps)` to do any why?

Comment: Also, `<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fc8101f76d0>` isn't an error. It's simply the printed represenation of a generator object, which is what is created by `(temps / 10 for temp in temps)`, which is called a *generator expression*. If you are new to Python, you probably should avoid these sorts of things until you have a handle on the basics of the language.

Answer (score 2):

Using parentheses around a comprehension makes it a generator expression; if you want a `list` comprehension, use square brackets:

```
new_temps = [temps / 10 for temp in temps]
```

Side-note: Your original `temps` isn't a `list` either (because you used parentheses, not square brackets as the delimiter); it's a `tuple` (similar to a `list`, but immutable). It works just fine in this case since you're not trying to modify it.

Answer (score 0):

First, `temps` is a tuple, not a list. A list would use square brackets:

```
temps = [345, 9876, 23, 100, 567]
```

For your use, it doesn't matter if it is a tuple or list, though.

Second, `(temps / 10 for temp in temps)` is a generator expression, not a list comprehension. You want

```
new_temps = [temps/10 for temp in temps]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a generator expression.

Either you need to use the corresponding list comprehension by using `[` ... `]` instead of `(` ... `)`:

```
temps = (345, 9876, 23, 100, 567)
new_temps = [temp / 10 for temp in temps]
print(new_temps)
```

gives

```
[34.5, 987.6, 2.3, 10.0, 56.7]
```

or you need to iterate over the generator:

```
temps = (345, 9876, 23, 100, 567)
new_temps = (temp / 10 for temp in temps)
for temp in new_temps:
    print(temp)
```

gives

```
34.5
987.6
2.3
10.0
56.7
```

You can also just convert it to a list (which works by iterating over it):

```
temps = (345, 9876, 23, 100, 567)
new_temps = (temp / 10 for temp in temps)
print(list(new_temps))
```

gives

```
[34.5, 987.6, 2.3, 10.0, 56.7]
```

(Iterating e.g. with a `for` loop will also work with the list comprehension used in the first option, although if you have a lot of items and *all* you are going to do is iterate once over it, then it is more efficient on memory to use the `(` ... `)` form.)

---

I have also corrected a bug in the generator expression - should be `temp / 10`, not `temps / 10`.

Comment: *generator expression

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You declare lists in python with [ ], also your for is calling all your list, not the element, which is "temp" not "tempts". It would be like this:

```
temps = [345, 9876, 23, 100, 567]
new_temps = [temp / 10 for temp in temps]
print(new_temps)
>> [34.5, 987.6, 2.3, 10.0, 56.7]
```

Good luck with your travel in Python!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to convert temps into list you can use:

```
list(temps)
```

Out: [345, 9876, 23, 100, 567]

But you can achieve your requirement without any conversion using list comprehension you can get your answer:

```
temps = (345, 9876, 23, 100, 567)
new_temps = [temp / 10 for temp in temps]
print(new_temps)
```

Out: [34.5, 987.6, 2.3, 10.0, 56.7]